# How can Nokogiri extract the Charset encoding of a scraped HTML document?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

Found a snippet that works for HTML Simple Dom Parser.

```
$el=$html->find('meta[http-equiv=Content-Type]',0);
$fullvalue = $el->content;
preg_match('/charset=(.+)/', $fullvalue, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

Can somebody help me to convert this so that this suits for Ruby and Nokogiri?

Answer (score 3):

[meta_encoding()](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/HTML/Document.html#method-i-meta_encoding)

Comment: This can't be answer.